# Matrix rearrangement and reorganizing in r

Tags: r

I have a matrix in r below. The values in rows are repeated based on the row number.

```
a1  a2  a3  0   0   0   0   0   0
a1  a1  a2  a2  a3  a3  0   0   0
a1  a1  a1  a2  a2  a2  a3  a3  a3
```

How can i rearrange the above matrix so that it becomes

```
a1  a2  a3  0   0   0   0   0   0
a1  a2  a3  a1  a2  a3  0   0   0
a1  a2  a3  a1  a2  a3  a1  a2  a3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` to loop through the rows of the matrix, subset the elements in each row to non-zero ('x1') and zero elements ('x2'), create a sequence grouped by the 'x1' elements with `ave`, then `order` the 'x1' based on on the sequence obtained, concatenate (`c`) with the zero elements in the vector, transpose (`t`) to get the output.

```
 t(apply(m1, 1, function(x) {
      x1 <- x[x!=0]
      x2 <- x[x==0]
      c(x1[order(as.numeric(ave(x1, x1, FUN=seq_along)))], x2)}))
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
#[1,] "a1" "a2" "a3" "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0" 
#[2,] "a1" "a2" "a3" "a1" "a2" "a3" "0"  "0"  "0" 
#[3,] "a1" "a2" "a3" "a1" "a2" "a3" "a1" "a2" "a3"
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c("a1", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a1", "a1",
"a3", "a2", "a1", 
"0", "a2", "a2", "0", "a3", "a2", "0", "a3", "a2", "0", "0", 
"a3", "0", "0", "a3", "0", "0", "a3"), .Dim = c(3L, 9L))
```

Comment: thanks, i am trying to rearrange based on the location, there is no sequence in the values but order based on the location. For example in row2 `a2` is offset by -1,+1. `a3` is offset by -2,0. In row3 `a2` is offset by -2,0,+2, `a3` is offset by -4,-2,0.

Comment: @HaagenDaz  I am not sure I understand your comment.  My solution is based on the example you shared.